# Dont see the html5 page in angular 5 routing,in url i in the dashboard

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a problem with httml when I try to get on it.
In URL changes, but the page itself is not visible, does not respond at all

The router outlet is working in dashboard.html

**DASHBOARD MODULE**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {DashboardRoutingModule} from './dashboard-routing.module';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    DashboardComponent
   ],
    declarations: [DashboardComponent]
  })
  export class DashboardModule { }
```

**DASHBOARD-ROUTING**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';

const dashboard: Routes = [
   {path:'', redirectTo:'dashboard',pathMatch:'full'},
   {path:'',component:DashboardComponent}

  ];

 @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboard)],
   exports:[RouterModule],
   })
  export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

**DASHBOARD COMPONENT**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatabaseService } from '../service/database.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 username:string;
 constructor(private database:DatabaseService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    alert('dashboard page');
    this.username = this.database.User.name;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to the 'dashboard' route but you don't have that route setup. Try changing to

```
{path:'', redirectTo:'dashboard',pathMatch:'full'},
{path:'dashboard',component:DashboardComponent}
```

The first line redirects users landing on `http://appurl/` to `http://appurl/dashboard`. Second line actually loads a component on that route.

Add bootstrap to your app module ..

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    DashboardComponent
   ],
    declarations: [DashboardComponent],
    bootstrap: [DashboardComponent]  <--------
  })
  export class DashboardModule { }
```

Comment: try using `'**'` instad of `''` on the first line

Comment: Check edited answer. You are missing a bootstrap declaration from the module.

Comment: Try to get a descriptive error. Add console.log statements and figure out at what level the route is failing to load.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you pasted, if Dashboard is AppModule, then change following line

```
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboard)],
```

to

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(dashboard)],
```

If Dashboard is child module (Lazy loaded), then

- assuming you have App module(parent module)
- use this property in your app modules

  RouterModule.**forRoot**(ROUTES, {
    enableTracing: true
  })

When you enable this, check your browser console for all the Routing logs. It will clearly show the routes being loaded.